# How to detect Finger Up to down / Down to up with coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

As I have `CustomView` where i want to detect `Touch Event` like when user do `Touch` Down/Up  and release or visa versa as in this Image.

[image]

**What I tried**

Swipe But in Which i Get only coordinate where user releasing the finger. like tap on `X = 100` and releasing on `10` and m getting `10` only.

**What i am looking for**

Want to get whole coordinate like user tap on `X = 100`  and release on `X = 80` then looking for on every single coordinate changed like `100,99,98,97,96,95,94.......80.` equally as finger moving.

Please if anyone have any idea about it or something i forget to do. 
Please Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to your .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    CGFloat touchStartPoint;
    CGFloat touchOffsetPoint;
    CGFloat tempTouchOffsetPoint;
}

@end
```

And this to your .m file

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    touchStartPoint=[touch locationInView:self.view].y;
    touchOffsetPoint = 0;
    tempTouchOffsetPoint = 0;
    //  NSLog(@"touchStartPoint = %f",touchStartPoint);   
}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    touchOffsetPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view].y - touchStartPoint;


    if (touchOffsetPoint>tempTouchOffsetPoint) {
        NSLog(@"touch down");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"touch up");
    }

    tempTouchOffsetPoint = touchOffsetPoint;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to put the ivars in the .h file. They should go in the .m file instead. Take advantage of modern Objective-C. The only things that should be in the .h file are things that other classes need to know about.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have done it:

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
 swipeGesture.direction =    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp|UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
 [self.gestureAreaView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
 [swipeGesture release];

  -(void)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender 
 {
//Gesture detect - swipe up/down , can't be recognized direction
 }
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
 swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
 [swipeGesture release];

 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture2 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
 swipeGesture2.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture2];
 [swipeGesture2 release];

 -(void)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender 
 {
//Gesture detect - swipe up/down , can be recognized direction
if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)
{
}
else if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)
{
}
}
```

Hope this helps out

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
// declared somewhere
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *touchPositions;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:self];
    [self.touchPositions addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:loc]];
}
```

Comment: But this giving the Coordinates user User tap. i required like user tap on x=100 and then coming downing like 99,98,96,97 all coordinates ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly do you need to achieve?

Comment: Yes this is good But with this i get only where user tap like on 100 and release on 80. looking for all

Comment: Create and array of `CGPoints` and add all coordinates to it in this method.